# Converting Dataset to a model class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

My Webservice is returning a dataset comprising of 1 table, which contains 135 columns.
I need to build a model class (in C#), which should have all 135 column names as property name of the class.

Is there any way by which I can use the filestream writer & build my class?

NB: I can easily convert the dataset to XML, but then I ve to do a lot of copy paste work to create the class manually. :(.

Comment: Old post but for others : very flexible class
https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/mapping-datatables-and-datarows-to-objects-in-csharp-and-net-using-reflection/

Answer (score 1):

There are actually ways to convert XML into classes in C#:

http://sharpertutorials.com/using-xsd-tool-to-generate-classes-from-xml/

But if the XML is from default serialization of the dataset then it will probably look horrendous.

Comment: Very true. The generated class is having too many additional & unnecessary information.

Comment: @Biki you could use it to get the bulk of the class and trim it down to just the properties.

Answer (score 1):

I got another approach as stated below:

Step 1: Convert your Dataset to a XML doc:

```
            var xmlSW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\xml\Krishna.xml");
            myDataset.WriteXml(xmlSW, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            xmlSW.Close();
```

Step 2: Convert your XML document to XSD doc.

```
   -> Open Visual Studio Command Promt.
   -> Type : xsd c:\xml\Krishna.xml (that is the path of the xml file.
```

For Eg:
C:\Windows\system32>xsd c:\xml\krishna.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'C:\Windows\system32\krishna.xsd'.

Step 3: Convert your xsd to C# class.

```
   -> Open Visual Studio Command Promt.
   -> Type : xsd krishna.xsd /classes
```

For Eg: 
C:\Windows\system32>xsd krishna.xsd /classes
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'C:\Windows\system32\krishna.cs'.

NB: The generated property name can be renamed properly (if not proper) by Resharper or similar tools.

The output class file might contain some unnecessary information that u need to clean up.
So this method is suitable if your dataset is returing huge tables containing hundreds of columns & you dont want to copy paste all of them manually to create your own mapping class.

Once you get the structure (class), you can use XmlSerializer to convert it to object or viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look into Scaffolding.  You can download it here:

[ASP.Net MVC Scaffold Generator](http://www.twinforms.com/products/mvcscaffold/index.php)

> MVC Scaffold Generator is a CRUD code generator for the new ASP.NET
>   MVC framework.
>
> MVC Scaffold Generator allows you to quickly create the basic
>   Add/Edit/Delete/List Asp.NET pages.

You can also watch a screencast here:

[ASP.Net MVC Scaffold Generator screencast](http://www.twinforms.com/screencast/asp.net/mvc_scaffold/)

Here is a Microsoft walkthrough:

[Using MVC View Templates with Data Scaffolding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405231.aspx)

Comment: Sorry Neil, I think Scaffolding wont help me to create c# classes from Dataset or XML document.